# iOS custom button has lost click functionality

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have made an iOS customrenderer for a Button in my PCL.

The button is a custom button, Hence why my PCL `Handle_clicked` event doesn't fire.

I suppose i need to add something in:

```
btn.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs c) =>
{
};
```

in order to make some sort of callback, so that my `Handle_clicked` event knows when the user has clicked the button. I just don't know how, as customrenderers are fairly new to me.

I have tried adding the following to my custom button:

```
UIButton btn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
btn = Control as UIButton; //I have added this
```

Unfortunately by doing so, it recognize the click event, but doesn't add my custom styling.

Comment: Thank you again @SushiHangover, but it says that the Control is a read only property?

Comment: Was not thinking, need more coffee, it is `SetNativeControl`, Search for `SetNativeControl` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Comment: i sort of got it working now.. however, if i place `base.OnElementChanged(e);` before my `If(control == null)` in which i set my new native control, my styling dissapears. Coming from .NET MVC, Why is this so hard...?